# How to configure Unity Container to NOT resolve unregitered Ienumerable

Tags: .net, unity-container

Unity resolves unregitered  Ienumerable as empty array. (in verion 5.8.11)  As I red on Github Unity developers see this as good default convention, and do not fix this.

This behavior can result some errors, which are hard to find. Is it possible to reconfigure Unity the way,  that it reject to resolve unregistered IEnumerable and quit Resolving with Exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution, but you can add a guard to your constructors that receive an `IEnumerable` to throw if it is empty.

Comment: Well it does not solve my problem. I would throw the exception in case if I do not have any of  object of some kind in database (because it does not used). This can be a normal case for some installation of Software. It is two different cases you can not resolve some list (because your registration is buggy, or you simple forgot register new feature)  and you resolve some list with zero element.

Comment: I doubt you can discern these two cases. Either there are types registered for an interface or there are no types registered. The container has no means to detect whether there are no types because nothing's in the databse (and it is thus correct that no types were registered) or because you made a typo in the registration.